# pkexec deny my password

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-minimal, pkexec

I am trying to fix an issue where pkexec deny my password on a minimal install from the mini-iso (started with only bash)
is there an other root password I am not aware of ? because I only have one user account on the machine.

```
spark:~$ Antidote9
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/opt/Druide/Antidote9/Application/Bin64/ConfigurateurSysteme.bin' as the super user
Authenticating as: spark,,, (spark)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon:  GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I barely have anything installed  (running i3wm)
is there something I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Possibly the same reason as here? [Running pkexec without a graphical agent fails even with falling back onto pkttyagent](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012)

Comment: nope ... it's letting me enter the password.  it's not creating a session cookie and the pkttyagent does not get the connection, it stays in a waiting state

Comment: never mind I got it to work ... only if the bash shell is the process running the command ....  meaning if an other program calls for pkexec I need to find it's pid